# How to strip files from a .blend

Tags: workflow

I am new and following a tutorial. The teacher links his final .blend file that I downloaded, but he uses a few backgrounds/videos etc that I need to strip out so I can use the same for my personal copy. How can I achieve that?

Comment: file external data pack the file

Answer (score 1):

You can pull from another .blend with File > Append.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> External Data -> Unpack All Into Files
[image: unpack]

Than select unpacking option that works best for you.

EDIT, If there is anythign else you want to transfer over like meshes or models you can use the Append option from the File menu than navigate his .blend file.